# MySQL - select row by user_id based on column value of other rows with the same user_id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a complicated request, so I have simplified it down, and hope I explain it well.

I have a table of Subscriptions:

```
ID   | Timestamp           | User Id | Status
-----+---------------------+---------+---------
1    | 2013-06-14 16:39:23 |    1    | inactive
2    | 2013-11-20 10:18:17 |    1    | active
3    | 2013-06-14 16:39:23 |    2    | inactive
4    | 2014-03-01 17:18:26 |    3    | active
```

I want to Query this table to find subscriptions which have a status of `inactive`, and who do **NOT** also have an `active` subscription.

For example, this should return Subscription ID 3, but not Subscription ID 1 - Because the User of ID 1 has an `active` subscription (being Subscription ID 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following and see if that works

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t
WHERE t.Status = 'inactive' 
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table t2 
                    WHERE t2.user_id = t.user_id 
                    AND t2.status <> 'inactive')
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me where I needed to be!

Comment: this query will not work if table has 3 rows for single user with inactive, active, inactive

Comment: Will test with Lashane's scenario

Comment: @ShawnWernig it does not work, as the order of status changes is not taken in account at all, try two variants: (inactive, active, inactive) - it should show last inactive, and (active, inactive, active) - it should not show anything

Answer (score 1):

following query should do the trick:

```
select a.id from
table as a
inner join
(
    select user_id, max(id)
    from table
    group by user_id
) as b
on (a.id=b.id and a.status='inactive')
```

Comment: Would this be faster?

Comment: @ShawnWernig if you have unique index on user_id, id and id, status - this should work quite fast

Comment: I do indeed. Thanks for the help!